# Xamarin SQLite-NET Stopwatch not found

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm getting `The type or namespace name 'Stopwatch' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Diagnostics' Are you missing an assembly reference?`

The project is a `PLC` and the build targets are 
   1. .NET framework 4 or later
  2. Silverlight 5
  3. WP8
  4. Windows Store App (Windows 8)
  5. Xamarin.Android
  6. Xamarin.iOS

if I uncheck silverlight and wp8, this error goes away, but comes more:
 `Thread.VolatileWrite isn't defined`
 `BindingFlags doesn't contain SetProperty`
and others

Comment: If you are migrating code to PCL, you'd better title the question as porting SQLite-NET to PCL. Vote to close this question as it is too broad. You are the one who should solve the challenge, and @Skall already shows the approach "for every error you meet, check the profile to see which platform lacks of that method or property".

Comment: I'm not migrating, copy/pasted SQLite-NET core file (as the title says) and the project wont build

Answer (score 0):

Stopwatch is not available in Silverlight but WP8 is OK. Have you tried Profile 78? WP8, NET4.5, Windows Store & Xamarin.

Comment: I'll try that and I'll let you know.

Comment: None of the profile works, they each let the project miss a different class

Comment: Instead of copying files try to get it from NuGet. If you search with sqlite-net you will get the original single file. You will also see SQLite.Net and SQLite.Net.Async which are assemblies and require platform specific DLL's on the client side.

Comment: I used NuGet to install sqlite-net and it's giving me the same errors on Profile 78